# Cron job connects but has 404 error

Tags: php, http, cron, scheduled-tasks, http-status-code-404

So i've had these cron jobs for years. They have worked fine this whole time, except for this past month.

The response of the cron job is as follows

```
--2012-08-03 00:00:01--  http://www.__domain__.com/cron/cleanSymFolder
Resolving www.__domain.com... 72.__.__.19
Connecting to www.__domain__.com|72.__.__.19|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-08-03 00:00:01 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I can go to the method in the browser just fine.
    domain.com/cron/cleanSymFolder">http://www.**domain**.com/cron/cleanSymFolder

It runs and is successful. Any ideas why CRON would be throwing a 404 even though it's connected, and even though I can hit the URL manually?

Also, it's 3 manual cron jobs I setup that do this. All 3 fail this way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from the infrormation you've presented it looks like environment issue.
Maybe some firewall was added on the way from the server you're running your cron jobs on to the web server you're trying to connect to.

Where do you run your browser? on your cron-jobs-running machine or just on your PC?

Is you cron job machine is windows or linux?

Assuming, its linux
I would suggest you to go directly to the machine you're running the jobs from and try to obtain the file (for example by using `wget` command). this way you'll see that you really can access the web server from this machine...

Hope this helps

Comment: Good idea. So the server is linux (ubuntu 11.04), and when I wget on the machine it returns the same error. In fact if I try to wget the main domain, I get the same error.  But I can wget other websites. So I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the domain being the same as the hostname? Or something like that?

Comment: well there can be a lot of issues here, but at least you've detected the issue, which is good :) Now, I would say that the chances are that its either a dns-related issue or something with security.

Comment: try to use wget along with ip address of you web server. if you succeed to get to that server, its dns related stuff. otherwise its probably firewalled... Good luck

Comment: Good call again, so wget with the IP works.  So I guess its a DNS issue, but an internal one.  I wonder what could be wrong, maybe something in the hosts file or hostname

Answer (score 0):

C'mon guys. Can't be DNS issue if he gets Status 404. My wild guess is that the remote server responds with 404 because of the user agent.